# Quick help with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I really need some quick help to create a regular expression to extract a price from a string. I will be using Javascript for this and the price may have two, three or four digits left of the decimal point.

Light AUD 59.00 H

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide us with your approach and the reasons why it didn't work.

Comment: are there always these 3 spaces in between? why not just explode the string and take the third part (59.00)

Comment: Time to learn regular expressions ;) http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: also a tool for javascript: http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your regex.

```
/\b(\d{2,4}\.\d{2})\b/
```

Comment: Should that not read /\s(\d{2,4}\.\d\d)\s/ to conform with t he stated specifications (2 to 4 digits before the dp, 2 after)

Comment: You need to add `\b` word boundary anchors around the regex to avoid matching the `2345.67` within `12345.67890`.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is a bit vague, but you can try something like this:

```
\s(\d+\.\d{2})\s
```

this assumes that there is a whitespaces before and after the price and that there are always 2 digits after the `.`. On the left of the dot it accepts any amount of digits but at least 1. You will find your price in the first capturing group.